# Unable to Instantiate UI Object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, unity-ui

I'm trying to instantiate an object in Unity whenever a function is called.

This is the start Method in my **UiHandler** script

```
public void Start() {

    GameObject obj = Instantiate(userPanelPrefab, userPanelContainer) as GameObject;

}
```

And this is my "OnPlayer" method, also in the **UiHandler** script, that is called every time a "player" enters the game. (They are not really players it is just names sent through a WebSocket server to Unity)

```
public void OnPlayer(WebsocketManager.PlayerEvent e) {
    Debug.Log("On Player");
    if (e.type == WebsocketManager.JOIN_TYPE) {
        Debug.Log("On Join");
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(userPanelPrefab, userPanelContainer) as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("Assign User Panel");
        UserPanel p = obj.GetComponent<UserPanel>();
        p.Set(e.name);
    }
}
```

When the start method is called, the Object instantiates as it should. But whenever the "OnPlayer" method is called, nothing happens and the code beneath the instantiate function doesn't even run. No errors or information is displayed in the console. It just does nothing.

The console output with the Debug messages is

- > On Player
- > On Join

the "Assign User Panel" log is also never displayed in the console.

For the WebSocket integration, I'm using [Socket Sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) and the back-end socket server is running on NodeJs.

This is my WebSocket code in my **WebsocketManager** script

```
public const string JOIN_TYPE = "join";
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://10.0.0.8:3069/");

ws.OnMessage += (sender, m) => {
 string json = GetStringFromArray(m.Data);
    if (IsJson(json, out PlayerEvent ev)) {
        Debug.Log("Is Valid JSON");
        if (ev.type == JOIN_TYPE) {
            AddPlayer(ev.name);
        } else if (ev.type == LEAVE_TYPE) {
            RemovePlayer(ev.name);
        }
        uiHandler.OnPlayer(ev);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you parent it to a canvas?

Comment: @BugFinder The userPanelContainer is part of the canvas. The userPanel should get instantiated with the container as the parent

Answer (score 0):

After you instantiate, you have to set the instantiated object to be a parent of the canvas, with InstantiatedObject.SetParent(canvasTransform);

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work for me. As soon as the instantiate method is called, no other code inside the function is run and the instantiate method doesn't create the object at all

Answer (score 0):

Update: I realised what was causing the lack of result from the instantiation. I was trying to instantiate from a different thread than the prefab. It caused the same condition as you had. Posting here in case someone has the same symptom in the future.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35462803)